# Why doesn't this function take a list as an argument?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I created this code to calculate an approximation to an integral, using the Trapezoid Rule and the Midpoint Rule.

Here the output is a table for N=16.

Question: what would be a simple way to create a table multiple values for N? Such as N=4, N=8 and N=16?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
n := 16
xA := 0
xB := 2
f[t_] := 1 + t^2
int := Integrate[f[t], {t, xA, xB}] // N
h := (xB - xA)/n
xT := xA + h*Range[0, n]
yT := f[xT]
T := h (Total[yT] - 1/2 First[yT] - 1/2 Last[yT]) // N
Terror := int - T
xM := xA + h*(Range[1, n] - 1/2)
yM := f[xM]
M := Total[h*f[xM]] // N
Merror := int - M
Grid[{{"Integral", "T", "T error", "M", "M error"}, {int, T, Terror, 
   M, Merror}}, Frame -> All]
```

I was hoping to simply declare a list: `n={4,8,16}`, but apparently that doesn't work. This kind of surprises me, because something like this would work:

```
g[x_] := x^2
mylist = {4, 8, 16}
g[mylist]
```

Comment: The simplest way probably would be to define everything as a function of `n`.

Comment: For a function to work with a `List` as an argument the same as if the function were mapped onto the `List`, the function must either 1) have the attribute `Listable` or 2) be composed of functions all of which are `Listable`. In your example, `g` acts as if it had the attribute `Listable` because its only component (`Power`) is `Listable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
xA := 0
xB := 2
f[t_] := 1 + t^2
int := Integrate[f[t], {t, xA, xB}] // N
h[n_] := (xB - xA)/n
xT[n_] := xA + h[n]*Range[0, n]
yT[n_] := f[xT[n]]
T[n_] := h[n] (Total[yT[n]] - 1/2 First[yT[n]] - 1/2 Last[yT[n]])//N
Terror[n_] := int - T[n]
xM[n_] := xA + h[n]*(Range[1, n] - 1/2)
yM[n_] := f[xM[n]]
M[n_] := Total[h[n]*f[xM[n]]] // N
Merror[n_] := int - M[n]
Grid[Join[{{"n", "Integral", "T", "T error", "M", "M error"}}, 
     Table[{n, int, T[n], Terror[n], M[n], Merror[n]}, {n, {4, 8, 16}}]],
     Frame -> All]
```

$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{n} & \text{Integral} & \text{T} & \text{T error} & \text{M} & \text{M error} \\
 4 & 4.66667 & 4.75 & -0.0833333 & 4.625 & 0.0416667 \\
 8 & 4.66667 & 4.6875 & -0.0208333 & 4.65625 & 0.0104167 \\
 16 & 4.66667 & 4.67188 & -0.00520833 & 4.66406 & 0.00260417 \\
\end{array}
$

You can also `Map` them like

```
Map[Merror, {4, 8, 16}]
```

> {0.0416667, 0.0104167, 0.00260417}